# How to get all the function names with their respective parameters from smart contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to fetch the list of all functions with their parameters which are present in any smart contract.

Comment: `const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(...);`

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(myContract, null, 4));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done only for contracts for which you have the ABI. Etherscan allows people to verify the contracts and the ABI becomes available through [Etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/apis#contracts). Then you just need to read the JSON file to find the function names and the types.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.
Can you please elaborate this using any specific example, that would be much more appreciable.